# SearchAdminDatabase in Not Responding

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration

While trying to patch this SP 2010 farm I came across this (take a look at the picture). Is there any way to fix this?
[image]

The DB is there alive and well on the SQL

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of reasons for this

- Make Sure Search Database exist on the SQL server
- Make sure SharePoint accounts have the permission on the that database( account which is running the app pool of search service app).
- Also check if Database is offline at SQL.

We had same issue with one of Content DB, where we found for some reason, DBA deleted the database at sql without informing us.

Comment: didn't help. database is there. there is actually a Search DB 2 also. can this be messing it up?

Comment: where is search DB2? on sharepoint or on sql?

Comment: the DB2 is on the SQL server